# While loop printing a response when it shouldn't - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, indentation

My program contains a simple 'Y/N' input. I have placed a while loop inside the code, which is supposed to respond when the input entered isn't 'Y/N' or any of it's variations.

```
import time
count_d = 10

load = input('Import modules? Y/N')

if load == 'Y' or load == 'y' or load == ' Y' or load == ' y':
    print('Modules loading...')
    while count_d >0:
        print(count_d)
        count_d = count_d-1
        time.sleep(1)
    print('Modules loaded')
elif load == 'N' or load == 'n' or load == ' N' or load == ' n':
    print('Shutdown initiated.')
    sys.exit()

while load != 'Y' or load != 'y' or load != ' Y' or load != ' y' and load != 'N' or load != 'n' or load != ' N' or load != ' n':
    print('This answer does not correspond with the desired output')
    load = input('Import modules? Y/N')
    if load == 'Y' or load == 'y' or load == ' Y' or load == ' y':
        print('Modules loading...')
        while count_d >0:
           print(count_d)
           count_d = count_d-1
           time.sleep(1)
        print('Modules loaded')
        break
    elif load == 'N' or load == 'n' or load == ' N' or load == ' n':
        print('Shutdown initiated.')
        break
```

When I do enter an accepted input, the program responds where it needs to, but also prints the response for the while loop, where it is designed to only recognise it with a unaccepted input. What errors have I made so it releases the wrong output when I have done it correctly?

Comment: Put the while loop inside an ```else``` block so it doesn't get entered into if either of the first conditions are true. It's entering it because of the ```or``` condition inside your while loop. You'd want all ```and```'s instead. Unless I'm misunderstanding your intentions...

Comment: @mgarey Thanks, it works now. Can you please explain further why you need to place it in an else block?

Comment: @matt-333 , see my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637757/2306662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your checks so as to not have to deal with so many cumbersome conditions:

```
if load.strip().lower() == 'y':
```

and

```
elif load.strip().lower() == 'n':
```

and

```
while load.strip().lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
```

Coincidentally, this last one will fix your error, which was happening because you were using `or` in place of `and`.

Answer (score 0):

The statements below the `if` and `elif` blocks are executed regardless of whether they did satisfy the conditions or not.

To make sure that those statements are executed ONLY when the conditions in the `if` and `elif` are not satisfied, `else` must be used

Include the `while` loop in the `else` block:

```
import time
count_d = 10

load = input('Import modules? Y/N')

if load == 'Y' or load == 'y' or load == ' Y' or load == ' y':
    print('Modules loading...')
    while count_d >0:
        print(count_d)
        count_d = count_d-1
        time.sleep(1)
    print('Modules loaded')
elif load == 'N' or load == 'n' or load == ' N' or load == ' n':
    print('Shutdown initiated.')
    sys.exit()
else:
    while load != 'Y' or load != 'y' or load != ' Y' or load != ' y' and load != 'N' or load != 'n' or load != ' N' or load != ' n':
        print('This answer does not correspond with the desired output')
        load = input('Import modules? Y/N')
        if load == 'Y' or load == 'y' or load == ' Y' or load == ' y':
            print('Modules loading...')
            while count_d >0:
               print(count_d)
               count_d = count_d-1
               time.sleep(1)
            print('Modules loaded')
            break
        elif load == 'N' or load == 'n' or load == ' N' or load == ' n':
            print('Shutdown initiated.')
            break
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the 'or' statements in your while loop to 'and' statements.

This example should show you why...

while(!a or !b):
//runs in the case that a is true but b is false

while(!a and !b):
//runs while a and b are both not true

Comment: That's not valid Python syntax. At the very least, switch `!` to `not`. Still, more helpful information could be added to *show* why this is the case.